# sending a string dynamically along with a UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I basically want to send a known string from a method I am in:

```
    NSString *websiteString;
    if(a==0)
          websiteString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"www.google.com"] autorelease];

    else
          websiteString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"www.yahoo.com"] autorelease];

    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aButton.frame = rct;

    // I get thrown in this next line: how do I initialize the Value for key?
    [aButton setValue:websiteString forKey:@"website"];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickedInsidePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

To the callback function, where I can load the sent string in the UIWebview...

-(void) clickedInsidePage:(id) sender{

```
   NSString *websiteString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[((UIControl *) sender) valueForKey:@"website"]] autorelease];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:websiteString]];
    NSLog(@"visiting: %@",websiteString);
    .
    .
    .

    }
```

But I get an error thrown because the key/Value was not actually set or initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an array of strings, then give the button tag property the index.  Then you can extract the tag to get the string:

```
NSArray * someArray = // website strings added here
```

In your if statement, set the button to match the index:

```
aButton.tag = 0;
```

Then use the index to get the string:

```
string = [someArray objectAtIndex: ((UIButton*)sender).tag];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use setValue to set a value for a non-existent key. UIButton doesn't have a property named 'website' which is why your code crashes. @Javy provides one possible, and good, solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use dictionary method on UIControl.

There are other better ways of fetching objects, in you case, a string, in a method like the one mentioned in @Javy's answer. 
But if you HAVE to add an extra properties to existing control, you'll have to subclass it and add a property in the subclass which you can get/set in the action.